# Process.Start PDF in a folder

Tags: pdf, directory, process.start

I can't get Process.Start to simply launch a PDF with default PDF viewer.

I tried so many combinations of shell execute, working folder etc etc. Keeps giving me either 'The system cannot find the file specified' or 'the directory name is invalid'

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        string filename = @"Milking and cooling software set 2018-39.pdf";
        MessageBox.Show(currentpath + @"\Astronaut A5 v1.5(b7)\documentation\" + filename);
        fullpath = currentpath + @"\Astronaut A5 v1.5(b7)\documentation";
        fullfile = fullpath + filename;
        ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo();
        process.WorkingDirectory = fullpath;
        process.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.FileName = fullfile;
        process.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Verb = "run as";
        Process.Start(process);
     }
```

Why is this so hard, I have tried for hours to simply lauch Acrobat Reader to open a PDF file. I can double click it no problem in it's location but C# can't open it, either I get .NET errors or Adobe opens and says it can't find the file. Tried so many combinations of "\"", full path, hard coded path etc etc...unbelievable that this is so hard to code in this day and age.

Comment: My compiled exe should just get current folder and open a pdf nested within the structure of current folder when they click a button.

Comment: Useless forum, no one helps here.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve told the system to *not* use ShellExecute. This means the path you’re giving should be an actual executable program. PDFs are not so if you want to open it with the default reader use ShellExecute.

```
process.UseShellExecute = true;
```

Also using “run as” as the verb doesn’t make any sense here, unless there is such a verb defined for PDFs which I’m pretty sure there isn’t. That should be removed.

Comment: When removing run as and shellexecute false,then I get System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Comment: process.FileName = "C:\\Users\\Dominic Legendre\\source\\repos\\SoftwarePanelA5\\SoftwarePanelA5\\bin\\Debug\\Astronaut A5 v1.5(b7)\\documentation\\Milking and cooling software set 2018-39.pdf"